# Having trouble with the error syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been stuck on this error for a while now, I've looked around and apparently it is due to too many `end` 's, but I can't seem to see why, any help guys? thanks.

Here's my code

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
      render "new"
  end
```

Comment: you're missing a `end` in your `if/else`, `create` action

Comment: i've edited your post. looking at the edits, it's easy to see where you are missing your 'ends'

Comment: You are missing the end for class and the end for the if statement as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end # your missed end here
  end
end # another end missed for the class
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help, I tried this but i still get the same error message. Could it be due to something else within my code?

Comment: @user1811817 yes your missed another end for the class see am updated

Comment: @RajInevitable.. I think formatting play a vital role in such type of errors so correct identation is really important while answering such type of questions.